# sudo python3 is running different version than running python3 without sudo

Tags: sudo, python

[I built and installed](https://www.scivision.dev/compile-install-python-beta-raspberry-pi/) python3.8 in raspbian and changed PATH

```
export PATH=$HOME/.local/bin/:$PATH
```

I run

```
>>which python3
/home/pi/.local/bin//python3
>>python3 --version
Python 3.8.0
>>whereis python3
python3: /usr/bin/python3.7m-config /usr/bin/python3.7m /usr/bin/python3.7 /usr/bin/python3.7-config /usr/bin/python3 /usr/lib/python3.7 /usr/lib/python3 /etc/python3.7 /etc/python3 /usr/local/lib/python3.7 /usr/include/python3.7m /usr/include/python3.7 /usr/share/python3 /home/pi/.local/bin/python3.8-config /home/pi/.local/bin/python3.8 /home/pi/.local/bin/python3 /usr/share/man/man1/python3.1.gz
```

however when I run

```
>>sudo python3 --version
Python 3.7.3
>>sudo which python3
/usr/bin/python3
```

how can I change **sudo python3** to point to 3.8

Comment: Yep what @steeldriver said; this is a typical `sudo` usage concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sudo -E COMMAND` in order to preserve the enviroinment of your user. In your case:

```bsh
sudo -E python3 --version
```

If the problem is still here, you can use the following command to override the path only for the selected command:

```bsh
sudo "PATH=$PATH" python3 --version
# OR
sudo env "PATH=$PATH" python3 --version
```

Comment: no It is still not working

Comment: this part worked sudo "PATH=$PATH" python3 --version
# OR
sudo env "PATH=$PATH" python3 --version

Comment: Any feedback regarding why -E option does not work in CenOS 7?